# pass textbox value to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have gridview control and textbox + button control in page aspx.

i want pass textbox value to gridview by click button.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvName" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and use this code:

```
protected void btnAddName_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (GridViewRow row in gvName.Rows)
        {
            if ((Label)row.FindControl("lblName") is Label)
            {
                ((Label)row.FindControl("lblName")).Text = txtName.Text;
            }
        }
     }
```

but its no ok. :-( please help me.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing it.can you please explain?

Comment: just you want to assign texbox value to label in gridview? What do u need exactly?

Comment: @Nag: Yes. i want insert value to gridview with texbox value

Comment: @AhmadRezaye: you want to assign text box to a selected row or all rows in a gridview. I think u want to add items to gridview from texbox on button click. Am I right?

Comment: @AhmadRezaye: Use a temporary datatable maintain it in session and add new items to datatable in session. and bind datatable to gridview. if u r not clear i will post code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If grid row has label with `id` lblName then you will get it from row and you do not need to check it again.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvName.Rows)
{
    Label lblName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblName");         
    lblName.Text = txtName.Text;            
}
```

**Note**: If you do not have rows already in thr gridview then you wont be able get the value in label. You need to ensure their are row(s) in grid.

Comment: i use this code in click button event but Does not work. not insert value to gridview.

Comment: i insert value in textbox and click but not insert value textboxt to gridview

Comment: You need to bind grid with data source, check it here how you bind with data table, http://forums.asp.net/t/1093452.aspx/1

Comment: i try this cod: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/362480/How-can-i-pass-the-value-from-text-box-to-label-in  but gridview is empty. :-(

Comment: Grid will is template for data to come. You wont see data unless you bind the grid.

Answer (score 3):

```
Create a rowdatabound command and place the below code. 

protected void gvName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblName");         
            lblName.Text = txtName.Text;  
        }
}
```

Comment: i use this code but not insert value to gridview. (gridview is empty)

Comment: First,bind the gridview with datasource and try this.